# Error when trying to grab json values using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, get

The following code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&relationship=all", false);
xhr.send();
```

gives me this error

`NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&relationship=all'.`

Why?

Comment: I would have expected a more explicit message for this, but wouldn't that be a same-origin issue?

Comment: Try and view the request and response headers using developer tools (F12 assuming chrome or firefox) network tab.  Possible the API is returning status code 500

Comment: The site returns data in JSON format, and not XML, is that a problem?

Comment: I get this error in the console in developer tools: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: if they support a jsonp option use that, otherwise re-proxy the JSON using YQL